# PHP constructor return object with pass by reference

Tags: php, oop, reference, constructor

I'm working on a PHP class that will fetch another class and somehow return it, obviously constructors can't return values so I was looking at passing by reference and this is what I got:

```
<?php
class Example {
    public function __construct($name,&$var){
        //This registers the class in my system (I know this part works)
        IceTray::$Registry->registerLibrary($name);
        //this fetches the object of the registered class above (I know it works)
        $var = IceTray::$Registry->Libraries->$name;
    }
```

Am I passing by reference wrong?  Because when I use this in my project:

```
$test = 0;
$lib = new Example('ClassName', $test);
$test->testing();
```

$Test is the variable I wish to store the object in, the first argument of the constructor is the name of the class to register and assign to the variable passed by reference which is the second argument.  The next line is called a method inside the requested class name, but it's not working.

No errors or anything, again I'm new to the passing by reference concept maybe I'm doing something wrong.  Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `var_dump($var);`, `var_dump($test);`

Comment: var_dump($var) at the beginning of the constructor is returning int(0) and the other two you requested are returning NULL.  So maybe it's an issue with the assignment, I will look into it.

Comment: "at the beginning of the constructor" --- check in the end. It's obvious that in the beginning it's `0`

Comment: Oops mistake in phrases in my part, when I said "and the other two you requested are returning NULL" I meant at the end of the constructor as well, it returns NULL.

Comment: that means `IceTray::$Registry->Libraries->$name` is `NULL`

Comment: I suppose, I'm working it out now.  Maybe it wasn't working after all, sometimes all I need is another eye to discover something, I will fill you in in a few.

Comment: Oh!! Yes I didn't write a the registerLibrary method correctly, had a small mistake.  Thanks for your help in making me fix this!  Some times I just need an outsiders mind!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Example {
    public $var = null;
    public function __construct($name){
        //This registers the class in my system (I know this part works)
        IceTray::$Registry->registerLibrary($name);
        //this fetches the object of the registered class above (I know it works)
        $this->var = IceTray::$Registry->Libraries->$name;
    }
}

$lib = new Example('ClassName');
$lib->var->testing();
```

Why hurt yourself and not use calls properties to return what you need?

Comment: It's to long and could be confusing as this will be distributed in a framework, it was my original system but it wasn't very nice to type.  I fixed the other way though, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @APott Who cares about typing... References are more complicated to grasp for a lot more PHP devs out there. You'll see :)

Comment: They won't notice as all they're typing is a variable name. `$library = new Library('Example',$library); $library->method();`

Comment: If I saw that code, I'd fire the one writing it. You initialize a variable and replace it on the same line. And... later on... someone looking for a bug will cry seeing that. Or missing it...

Comment: That's optional, so if you use it and you don't want to fire yourself you could do this. `$object; new Library('Example',$object); $object->method()` or even drop the first declaration since it's valid PHP.